# How to find all unique permutations of a set of elements over a graph

Tags: python, networkx, python-itertools

I have a material science problem which I am reasonably sure can be solved using networkx, but I'm not sure how.

Firstly I would like to find all unique combinations of 3 elements, with replacement. This I have already done with itertools as follows:

```
elements = ["Mg","Cu","Zn"]
combinations = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(elements, 3))
```

For each of these combinations, I would like to find all unique permutations over a simple graph. The graph has three nodes and three edges, where each node is connected to two other nodes. Importantly, the edges have a distance of 1, but one of the edges has a distance of 2. Basically, like a right-angle triangle.

e.g. something like Node1 <-Distance=1-> Node2 <-Distance=2-> Node3 <-Distance=1-> Node1

So for the combination ["Mg", "Cu", "Cu"] there should be two unique permutations:

*a*) Mg(site1) -1- Cu(site2) -1- Mg(site3) -2- Mg(site1)
*b*) Mg(site1) -1- Mg(site2) -1- Cu(site3) -2- Mg(site1)
***c*) Cu(site1) -1- Mg(site2) -1- Mg(site3) -2- Cu(site1) (This is the same as *b*)**

NOTE: I'm not sure of the best way to define the graph, it could be something like:

```
import networkx as nx
FG = nx.Graph()
FG.add_weighted_edges_from([(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2)])
```

Comment: How are you defining this graph in code, exactly?

Comment: I don't know how I would define it, any method which gives me three nodes and encodes the proper distances would be fine for me.

Comment: I added a possible way of generating the graph.

Comment: A "simple graph" cannot have edges from a node to itself - but in your examples the node Mg has an edge to itself every time. Please clarify.

Comment: You can think of it as Mg1 and Mg2, imagine something like H2O, where you have two distinct atoms, 'H' but of the same element.

Comment: @DanielMarchand But your input is `["Mg", "Cu", "Cu"]`, so why are there two distinct Mg nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The uniqueness criteria you want to use is called [graph isomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism). NetworkX has a submodule for it: [networkx.algorithms.isomorphism](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/isomorphism.html). You can specify how exactly your nodes/edges of graphs should be treated as "equal" with `node_match/edge_match` parameters. Here is the example:

```
import networkx as nx

FG1 = nx.Graph()
FG1.add_node(1, element='Cu')
FG1.add_node(2, element='Cu')
FG1.add_node(3, element='Mg')
FG1.add_weighted_edges_from([(1, 2, 1), (2, 3, 1), (3, 1, 2)])

FG2 = nx.Graph()
FG2.add_node(1, element='Cu')
FG2.add_node(2, element='Mg')
FG2.add_node(3, element='Cu')
FG2.add_weighted_edges_from([(1, 3, 1), (2, 3, 1), (1, 2, 2)])

nx.is_isomorphic(
    FG1,
    FG2,
    node_match=lambda n1, n2: n1['element'] == n2['element'],
    edge_match=lambda e1, e2: e1['weight'] == e2['weight']
)
```

> `True`

If you will rename any element or change any edge weight, graphs will become non-isomorphic (with those parameters). It is how you can find unique graphs - the set of non-isomorphic graphs. Note, that graph isomorphism problem is very computational-heavy so you should not use it even for medium-sized graphs.

---

But your task has so many restrictions that graphs usage is not necessary. If you have only 3 element in a "molecule", you will have only 3 types of element combinations:

```
1-1-1

1-1-2

1-2-3
```

For each of them you can calculate and state the number of unique combinations:

`1-1-1`: One - `1=1-1`

`1-1-2`: Two - `1=1-2` and `1-1=2`

`1-2-3`: Three - `1=2-3`, `1-2=3` and `1-2-3(=1)`

So you can just multiply each itertools-combination to the number of possible combinations:

```
number_of_molecular_combinations = 0
for c in combinations:
    number_of_molecular_combinations += len(set(c))
print(number_of_molecular_combinations)
```

> `18`

This method will work FAR faster than graph processing but is usable only in the case of very strong restrictions, like yours.

Comment: This is wonderful thank you. In my research, I would be interested trying to study clusters of arbitrary size N (ok N might not be so large). Is there a way, using networkx or otherwise, to generate the number of unique combinations? Will it always be the length of the set of elements?

Comment: 1. You can still use the first variant, with graphs. It is usable for about `N<=15`. 2. No, it works only for `N=3`. For `N>=4` you should use combinatoric formulas (but it will still far faster than graph processing). Formulas will be different if element can be connected with each other or not.

Comment: And to clarify, the first variant would involve manually building a list of graphs, but checking every new entry against every existing entry against the 'is_isomorphic' property?

Comment: You can create all graphs programmatically (in the `itertools.combinations` loop, for example) and store them in a list or set. For each new graph you check is it isomorphic to each graph in the list. If it is isomorphic to any graph in the list, you DON'T append it. If not, you append it so you will check an isomorphism of every new graph to this graph too.